# Alternating sum over collections of sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, simplicial-complexes, mobius-inversion

Let $\mathbf{P}$ be a collection of subsets of a finite set $X$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the set of all subsets $\mathbf{S}\subset \mathbf{P}$ such that $\bigcup_{S\in \mathbf{S}} S = X$. Can one give a sensible upper bound on the sum
$$\Sigma = \sum_{\mathbf{S}\in \mathscr{S}} (-1)^{|\mathbf{S}|},$$
where $|\mathbf{S}|$ is the number of elements of $\mathbf{S}$? In particular: is the absolute value of the sum bounded by the number of minimal elements of $\mathscr{S}$?

(For a strategy that does not work, see [Alternating sum over collections closed under containment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364664/alternating-sum-over-collections-closed-under-containment?noredirect=1#comment920334_364664)).

What if every set $S$ in $\mathbf{P}$ is of cardinality $\leq l$, and $|X|=m\geq l$? Can one give a non-trivial bound in terms of $m$ and $l$?

Comment: Is not it the same question?

Comment: How? It's a special case. Or can every question of the other kind be put in this framework?

Comment: It would not surprise me if the simplicial complex $\mathscr{S}$ you describe has a name, but I'm not sure how one might google for that...

Comment: Well, $\mathbf{P}$ need not be the set of *all* subsets of $X$ of cardinality $\leq l$.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that you allow $\mathbf{P}$ to be not necessarily all the subsets.

Comment: Why a special case? Any contaitment-closed family has such a structure, does not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Not obvious to me - am I being dense?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: equivalently you are saying any simplicial complex can be realized via this construction. That's plausible but like H.A. I do not see it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to prove that the question about minimal elements is equivalent to the previous, namely:

**Theorem.** Assume that $\mathbf{P}$ is a finite set and $\mathscr{S}$ is a family of subsets of $\mathbf{P}$ which is closed under taking over-sets. Then there exists a finite set $X$ and an injection $\varphi:\mathbf{P}\to 2^X$ such that
$$
\mathscr{S}=\{\mathbf{S}\subset \mathbf{P}:\cup_{j\in \mathbf{S}}\varphi(j)=X\}.
$$

**Proof.**
For any set $\mathbf{S}\subset \mathbf{P}$ such that $\mathbf{S}\notin \mathscr{S}$ choose an element $x_{\mathbf{S}}$ which does not belong to all sets $\varphi(i),i\in \mathbf{S}$, and does belong to all $\varphi(j),j\notin \mathbf{S}$. Define $X=\sqcup_{\mathbf{S}} \{x_{\mathbf{S}}\}$, $\varphi$ is already defined. If $\mathbf{S}\notin \mathscr{S}$, then $\cup_{j\in \mathbf{S}}\varphi(j)\ne X$, because of the element $x_{\mathbf{S}}$. Now take
$\mathbf{S}\in \mathscr{S}$. Fix any element $x_{\mathbf{T}}\in X$, where $\mathbf{T}\notin \mathscr{S}$. Since all over-sets of $\mathbf{S}$ belong to $\mathscr{S}$, we conclude that $\mathbf{T}$ is not an over-set of $\mathbf{S}$, i.e., there exists $j\in \mathbf{S}\setminus \mathbf{T}$. The set $\varphi(j)$ covers $x_{\mathbf{T}}$. Since the element $x_{\mathbf{T}}\in X$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\cup_{j\in \mathbf{S}}\varphi(j)=X$.

Comment: OK, I think this works, and disproves that the absolute sum is bounded by the number of minimal sets of $\mathscr{S}$. At the same time, the set $X$ is pretty large (it can be of size $2^{|\mathbf{P}|}$ or close to that), so one can still have a useful bound for this problem (see my answer) and not for the other one.

Answer (score 3):

The two versions of the problem are fully equivalent. Suppose $X$ is a finite set and $\mathbf{P}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Let's define
$$f(\mathbf{P})\mathrel{\mathop:}=\sum_{S\in \mathbf{P}}(-1)^{|S|} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(\mathbf{P})\mathrel{\mathop:}= \sum_{S_1,S_2,\dots,S_r\in \mathbf{P}\\ S_1\cup \cdots \cup S_r=X}(-1)^r.$$
Let's also denote by $\widehat {\mathbf{P}}$ the set of all subsets which contain some element of $\mathbf{P}$. The following holds:
$$g(\mathbf{P})=g(\mathbf{\widehat{\mathbf{P}}})=f(\widehat{\mathbf{P}}).$$
To prove the first equality notice that if $A_0\subset A_1$ are subsets such that $A_0\in \mathbf{P}$ and $A_1\notin \mathbf{P}$ then
$$g(\mathbf{P}\cup\{A_1\})-g(\mathbf{P})=\sum_{S_1,S_2,\dots,S_r\in \mathbf{P}\\ A_1\cup S_1\cup \cdots \cup S_r=X}(-1)^{r+1}$$
however the collections that index the sum on the right split into those that contain $A_0$ and those that don't. These two cancel each other out and the sum evaluates to zero.  Since we can keep adding subsets to $\mathbf{P}$ one by one, this shows that $g(\mathbf{P})=g(\widehat{\mathbf{P}})$. Finally, the equality $g(\widehat{\mathbf{P}})=f(\widehat{\mathbf{P}})$ was proven by Fedor in the previous question (sidenote: this is referred to as Rota's crosscut theorem).

---

A third equivalent formulation is to ask for bounds on the Euler characteristic of the simplicial complex obtained by using $X$ as a set of vertices and adding a simplex for $S$ whenever the complement of $S$ is in $\widehat{\mathbf{P}}$. Thus your questions become:

1. What is the largest Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex with $N$ facets?
2. What is the largest Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex with $N$ facets and $m$ vertices?
3. What is the largest Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex on $m$ vertices if all facets have dimension $\geq m-l$

The answer to Q1 is $\binom{N-1}{ \lfloor (N-1)/2 \rfloor}$ by the Sagan-Yeh-Ziegler paper. They construct a simplicial complex with $N$ vertices, $\binom{N}{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}$ facets, with Euler characteristic \binom{N-1}{ \lfloor (N-1)/2 \rfloor}, which also gives a simplicial complex with the same Euler characteristic but $N$ facets and $\binom{N}{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}$ vertices. The answer to Q2 was conjectured to be $e^{O(\log N\log m)}$ by David Speyer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91712/is-euler-characteristic-of-a-simplicial-complex-upper-bounded-by-a-polynomial-in), and I don't know what the status of this is.

For Q3, if $m-l\le \frac{m}{2}$ then we can use the same example in Q1 which gives the answer $\binom{m-1}{\lfloor (m-1)/2\rfloor}$. If $m-l\geq m/2$ then the number of facets is at most $\binom{m}{l}$ and assuming Speyer's conjecture the correct upper bound should be $e^{O(\log m \cdot \log \binom{m}{l})}$.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the SYZ paper bounding the Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex with a given number of *vertices*, not facets?

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, it is, but it implies the bound for fixed facets, as mentioned in David's answer I linked to.

Comment: How do the bound $N\leq \binom{m}{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}$ and the bound $\chi \leq \binom{N-1}{\lfloor (N-1)/2\rfloor}$ imply that $\chi \leq \binom{m-1}{\lfloor (m-1)/2\rfloor}$? I must be missing something.

Comment: What I am looking for now is something that is both (a) unconditional and (b) at least as good as the (unconditional) bound I clumsily gave in my own answer below. The bound there is good enough for my purposes, but of course I'd prefer something more literate than what I was able to give!

Comment: @HAHelfgott I made a small edit to clarify. I just meant that the case $m-l\le m/2$ can still be optimized with the SYZ construction.

Comment: (The above answer is nice, but I'd perhaps be a bit careful with "fully equivalent", in that the dependencies may be different: the number of minimal elements in $\mathbf{P}$ may be much larger than $X$, no? In that case, we are losing something when we reduce the new problem to the old problem and back.)

Comment: @HAHelfgott The number of minimal elements of $\mathbf{P}$ is the same as the number of minimal elements of $\widehat{\mathbf{P}}$ which is what i meant by fully equivalent.

Comment: Well, sure, but if you are interested in a bound with a good dependency on $m$ and $l$, reduction to the older problem may not necessarily be the way to go, no?

Comment: @HAHelfgott I'm not changing the sets in this reduction. The ground set $X$ stays the same, so $m$ doesn't change, and the minimal sets stay the same as well. As far as the comment about an unconditional bound: Once you know that a simplicial complex on $m$ vertices has $\chi \le \binom{m}{m/2}\le 2^m$ this is automatically better than the bound $l^m$ for $l\geq 3$.

Comment: Yes, here $X$ doesn't change, but the bound given in the older question has (in effect) the set of minimal elements of $S$ as its ground set.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Yes, I was being dense. You're right. I just hope this clarifies that knowing the optimal answer to one question leads to knowing the optimal answer for the other.

Comment: On Sagan-Yeh-Ziegler: is the Möbius function of a lower-order ideal $\mathcal{F}$ simply $\sum_{S\in \mathcal{F}} (-1)^{|S|}$? In that case a direct application to $\mathcal{F} = \{X\setminus S: S\in \widehat{P}\}$ does give the bound $\chi \leq \binom{m-1}{\lfloor (m-1)/2\rfloor}$ immediately.

Comment: Well, minus that, really. Yes, that seems to be stated in equation (1), section 2, of Sagan-Yeh-Ziegler.

Comment: @HAHelfgott That's correct.

Comment: But then $\chi\leq 2^m$ already follows from the trivial bound $f(\widehat{P})\leq |\widehat{P}|\leq 2^m$ and $g(P) = f(\widehat{P})$.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Good point :) If we want to get a considerable distance away from that trivial bound we need to restrict the class of simplicial complexes in a way that doesn't include the SYZ example.

Comment: Well, $\chi\leq 2^m$ is not in itself obvious, its proof now is elegant, and it's strong enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very naive but arguably non-trivial bound. (Please feel free to do better!)

Just choose a set $S_0$ in $\mathbf{P}$. It is clear that, for $\mathbf{S}\subset \mathbf{P}$ not containing $S_0$, if $\mathbf{S}$ is in $\mathscr{S}$, then the contributions of $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{S}\cup \{S_0\}$ to the sum $\Sigma$ cancel out. Hence $$\Sigma = - \mathop{\sum_{\mathbf{S}\subset \mathbf{P}}}_{\mathbf{S}\not\in \mathscr{S} \wedge (\mathbf{S}\cup \{S_0\}\in \mathscr{S})} (-1)^{|\mathbf{S}|} = - \sum_{T\subset S_0, T\neq \emptyset}\, \sum_{\mathbf{S}\in \mathscr{S}_{X\setminus T}} (-1)^{|\mathbf{S}|},$$
where, for $Y\subset X$, we denote by $\mathscr{S}_{Y}$ the set of all subsets $\mathbf{S}\subset \mathbf{P}$ such that $\bigcup_{S\in \mathbf{S}} S = Y$.

Thus, $|\Sigma|\leq a_{m,l}$, where $a_{m,l}$ is given by the following recurrence relation:
$$a_{m,l} = \sum_{i=1}^{\min(l,m)} \binom{l}{i} a_{m-i,l},$$
with $a_{0,l}=1$.

It is easy to show that $l^m\leq a_{m,l} \leq ((e-1) l)^m$.

Comment: Have you looked at Moebius inversion on finite posets? My only reference for it is chapter 5 section 7 in " Algebras, Lattices, Varieties".  Gerhard "Looking For A Mu Twist" Paseman, 2020.07.03.

Comment: It looks as if it might conceivably be related, but I'm completely unfamiliar with the formalism. Can you see a more precise link?